# PayPal Payflow Link Show Unable to place Order, Please Try Again

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-payflow-pro

I use magento v2.1.0, I input Partner, vendor, user and password.
but When I buy product and checkout 
I go to Review & Payment step It's show Contiune Button , I click continue it show "Unable to place Order, Please Try Again"

I don't know why. and I search  about problem on google but not successful.
Now customers can not buy on my site. Help me Please.

Thank very much.

Comment: You can check exact error in __debug.log__ file which is in __var/log__ folder. Make sure you must enable debug yes from admin settings.

Comment: [2018-01-05 06:12:15] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/e753256b6065a94881e5fcd7d5dc5f5f/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_241","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2018-01-05 06:12:15] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/e753256b6065a94881e5fcd7d5dc5f5f/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_17","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: It's show after i click continue on review & payment step  it's show 2 line

Answer (score 0):

Review & Payment step , I click continue it show "Unable to place Order, Please Try Again"

[image]